# IMAP - search for all messages in a conversation thread by references

Tags: email, search, imap

Please don't mark this as a duplicate of 16816425 because that one has incorrect search syntax which is corrected in this question. It is also not a duplicate of 6088914 because this question is about IMAP, not Gmail's IMAP extension.

I'm working on an IMAP client, and would like to be able to find a list of all messages that are referenced in a conversation thread.

I know that the "References" header includes a list of messages referenced in a conversation, so I tried searching it like so:

```
C: 3 SEARCH HEADER References {48}
S: + go ahead
C> <C63EF8D6-6874-401B-9E8C-B1D63B633246@gmail.com>
```

But it returns nothing. I've successfully searched for a single message using the "Message-ID" header, like so:

```
C: 3 SEARCH HEADER Message-Id {48}
S: + go ahead
C> <8D7F7FD5-9CD8-4D4B-BC8B-E1A3BC217350@gmail.com>
```

Is there any way to do this using IMAP 4?

Of course, I manually checked that <8D7F7FD5-9CD8-4D4B-BC8B-E1A3BC217350@gmail.com> was in the "References:" field in some emails in that mailbox and that very email is in the same mailbox too.

The above test was done against GMAIL.

NOTE: A google search suggested that gmail doesn't support RFC5256. I am validating if searching "References:" works before falling back to modify the IMAP library to use Gmail-specific IMAP command X-GM-THRID.

Comment: Perhaps Gmail does not support searching this header.  It may be worthwhile downloading this header (using BODY[HEADER.FIELDS]), caching it locally in a database, and searching that.

Comment: yahoo is ruder, simply dropping the connection when someone searches that. I guess it is a DDOS protection. So if you are sure at least one IMAP server can return a result on that one, hence the syntax and method are correct, I'll rename the issue to relate to GMAIL in the title.

Comment: It works on my Courier server.  `b UID SEARCH HEADER REFERENCES "<20141119210509.283291906.43351.4@example.net>"` responds with 
`* SEARCH 743`

Comment: Hi, I provided an answer in 16816425. Can you please clarify in which ways this question is not a duplicate?